# Calling a webservice in camel having the soap request as String

Tags: web-services, apache-camel

I want to call a Web Service using Apache Camel and I have the SOAP message in the form of String. Can anyone kindly let me know how to send SOAP request in form of String in Camel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example. If you need to perform some modifications of SOAP request string you can just change "constant" to something like "spel"

```
<setBody><constant><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <MyAction>
     <myparam>ABC</myparam>
  </MyAction>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>]]></constant></setBody>
<setHeader headerName="SOAPAction"><constant>MySOAPAction</constant></setHeader>
<setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod"><constant>POST</constant></setHeader>
<setHeader headerName="Content-Type"><constant>text/xml;charset=UTF-8</constant></setHeader>
<to uri="http://myserver:1234" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends of what type of endpoint you have for your outbound webservice.

1. If it is a CXF JAX-WS then it depends on what `dataFormat` property is set to: POJO or PAYLOAD.

   For POJO you have take SOAP headers, SOAP Body elements, unmarshal them to JAXB Pojos, then set them to Camel Exchange Body properly pass Exchange to endpoint
   For PAYLOAD - I'm not sure but maybe you can pass your string as is (or just SOAP body and SOAP headers elements) as strings. If not, check what CXF expects to get when `dataFormat` is PAYLOAD. (I just used it long time back).
2. For simple http endpoint just pass your string to it "as is" in the body with Http-method POST and Content-type header as `application/xml`